# Amazon RDS with MariaDB

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am starting in the amazon services, currently amazon has tutorials on how to connect amazon rds with mariadb through Workbench, but it has caused some doubts because I am developing for android.

**How do I connect the database to android studio?**

**When I make the consultations, do they go to workbench and then to amazon?**

**Is it necessary to develop an api to consult safely?**

I know they are questions for beginners but I searched the internet and I can not find the answers.

Answer (score 0):

To connect the database to android studio please refer the below link:

https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-database-android-application-in-android-s

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for answering, my only doubt regarding sqlite is if it only works as a local database? Or if it is possible that it is a database via server.